# Using regex to extract an image url from string

Tags: javascript, regex, string-parsing

I have a string that looks like this:

```
var complicatedString = "<![CDATA[<img src=\"http://l.yimg.com/a/i/us/we/52/32.gif\"/>\n<BR />\n<b>Current Conditions:</b>\n<BR />Sunny\n<BR />\n<BR />\n<b>Forecast:</b>\n<BR /> Fri - Sunny. High: 23Low: 13\n<BR /> Sat - Thunderstorms. High: 25Low: 15\n<BR /> Sun - Thunderstorms. High: 28Low: 21\n<BR /> Mon - Partly Cloudy. High: 24Low: 17\n<BR /> Tue - Partly Cloudy. High: 26Low: 18\n<BR />\n<BR />\n<a href=\"http://us.rd.yahoo.com/dailynews/rss/weather/Country__Country/*https://weather.yahoo.com/country/state/city-23511893/\">Full Forecast at Yahoo! Weather</a>\n<BR />\n<BR />\n(provided by <a href=\"http://www.weather.com\" >The Weather Channel</a>)\n<BR />\n]]>"
```

I need to extract **http://l.yimg.com/a/i/us/we/52/32.gif**.  The regex I came up with is:

```
var re = /(alt|title|src)=(\\"[^"]*\")/i;
```

See Fiddle:  https://jsfiddle.net/47rveu62/2/

I'm not sure why but this isn't working.

```
var re = /(alt|title|src)=(\\"[^"]*\")/i;
var m;
do {
  m = re.exec(complicatedString);
} while(m !== null);
```

**Update:** Regex 101 claims it works https://regex101.com/r/oV2hO2/1

Comment: Define "isn't working".

Comment: I can't get a match.  `m` is always `null`

Comment: `alert(m[0])` always fails.  Regex101 says I should get matches https://regex101.com/r/oV2hO2/1

Comment: There's no `alert(m[0])` in your code. And the string in your regex101 is different: It has backslashes in it; the one in your code doesn't.

Comment: There's an `alert(m[0])` if you visit the Fiddle in my post.  https://jsfiddle.net/47rveu62/2/

Comment: OK, that code is crazy. But apart from the potentially infinite loop, the problem is that your regex looks for a backslash but your search string doesn't contain one.

Comment: There's no danger of infinite loops, unless the string itself is infinite length.  The regex search finishes when there are no more matches.

Comment: Dude, you keep searching the same string. If it matches once, it will keep matching forever.

Comment: If you need more clarifications, I'm happy to provide.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is with the regex.

The backslashes in the string are used to escape the double-quote inside double-quoted string. **The backslashes are the escape characters and not part of the string.** So, in regex those are not required.

[image: Here's how the string looks when logged in console]

```
var re = /(alt|title|src)=(\\"[^"]*\")/i;
                           ^^      ^     // Remove those
```

Use

```
/(alt|title|src)=("[^"]*")/gi;
```

The `g` flag here is required as the `lastIndex` property of the regex is not updated by [`RegExp#exec`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/exec) and the next iteration the regex will start search from the same index and will thus go in infinite loop.
[**MDN**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/exec#Finding_successive_matches)

```js
var complicatedString = "<![CDATA[<img src=\"http://l.yimg.com/a/i/us/we/52/32.gif\"/>\n<BR />\n<b>Current Conditions:</b>\n<BR />Sunny\n<BR />\n<BR />\n<b>Forecast:</b>\n<BR /> Fri - Sunny. High: 23Low: 13\n<BR /> Sat - Thunderstorms. High: 25Low: 15\n<BR /> Sun - Thunderstorms. High: 28Low: 21\n<BR /> Mon - Partly Cloudy. High: 24Low: 17\n<BR /> Tue - Partly Cloudy. High: 26Low: 18\n<BR />\n<BR />\n<a href=\"http://us.rd.yahoo.com/dailynews/rss/weather/Country__Country/*https://weather.yahoo.com/country/state/city-23511893/\">Full Forecast at Yahoo! Weather</a>\n<BR />\n<BR />\n(provided by <a href=\"http://www.weather.com\" >The Weather Channel</a>)\n<BR />\n]]>";

var re = /(alt|title|src)=("[^"]*")/gi;
var m;
while(m = re.exec(complicatedString)) {
    console.log(m[2]);
}
```

---

I'd suggest you to use following regex

```
/img.*?src=("|')(.*?)\1/i;
```

```js
var complicatedString = "<![CDATA[<img src=\"http://l.yimg.com/a/i/us/we/52/32.gif\"/>\n<BR />\n<b>Current Conditions:</b>\n<BR />Sunny\n<BR />\n<BR />\n<b>Forecast:</b>\n<BR /> Fri - Sunny. High: 23Low: 13\n<BR /> Sat - Thunderstorms. High: 25Low: 15\n<BR /> Sun - Thunderstorms. High: 28Low: 21\n<BR /> Mon - Partly Cloudy. High: 24Low: 17\n<BR /> Tue - Partly Cloudy. High: 26Low: 18\n<BR />\n<BR />\n<a href=\"http://us.rd.yahoo.com/dailynews/rss/weather/Country__Country/*https://weather.yahoo.com/country/state/city-23511893/\">Full Forecast at Yahoo! Weather</a>\n<BR />\n<BR />\n(provided by <a href=\"http://www.weather.com\" >The Weather Channel</a>)\n<BR />\n]]>";

var regex = /img.*?src=("|')(.*?)\1/i;
var match = complicatedString.match(regex)[2];
console.log(match);
```

Comment: Thank you.  This is the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a probably naive regex that works on your input:
`/(https?:\/\/.*\.(?:png|jpg|gif))/`

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like an XY problem, and regex may not be necessary.

You're using the Yahoo! Weather API.  The codes for the images are available directly in the API, so there is no need to parse the result to find the image.

Here is an example API endpoint: https://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select%20*%20from%20weather.forecast%20where%20woeid%20in%20(select%20woeid%20from%20geo.places(1)%20where%20text%3D%22nome%2C%20ak%22)&format=json&env=store%3A%2F%2Fdatatables.org%2Falltableswithkeys

The different status images are saved as the `code` property.  You can access that image code directly.  Here is an example that pulls the image code, date, and weather description.

```
var apiUrl = "https://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select%20*%20from%20weather.forecast%20where%20woeid%20in%20(select%20woeid%20from%20geo.places(1)%20where%20text%3D%22nome%2C%20ak%22)&format=json&env=store%3A%2F%2Fdatatables.org%2Falltableswithkeys"

function appendToBody(obj) {
    document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0].innerHTML += ("<div><img src='http://l.yimg.com/a/i/us/we/52/"+obj.code+".gif' />" + obj.date +": "+obj.text+"</div>");
}


function loadDoc() {
  var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (xhttp.readyState == 4 && xhttp.status == 200) {
     var response = JSON.parse(xhttp.responseText);
     var current = response.query.results.channel.item.condition;
     appendToBody(current);



     var forecast = response.query.results.channel.item.forecast;

     for(var i = 0; i < forecast.length; i++) {
            appendToBody(forecast[i]);
     }
    }
  };
  xhttp.open("GET", apiUrl, true);
  xhttp.send();
}


loadDoc();
```

Example output:

> <div><img src="http://l.yimg.com/a/i/us/we/52/26.gif">Fri, 10 Jun 2016 06:00 AM AKDT: Cloudy</div>
>   <div><img src="http://l.yimg.com/a/i/us/we/52/26.gif">10 Jun 2016: Cloudy</div>
>   <div><img src="http://l.yimg.com/a/i/us/we/52/28.gif">11 Jun 2016: Mostly Cloudy</div>
>   <div><img src="http://l.yimg.com/a/i/us/we/52/26.gif">12 Jun 2016: Cloudy</div>
>   <div><img src="http://l.yimg.com/a/i/us/we/52/12.gif">13 Jun 2016: Rain</div>
>   <div><img src="http://l.yimg.com/a/i/us/we/52/28.gif">14 Jun 2016: Mostly Cloudy</div>
>   <div><img src="http://l.yimg.com/a/i/us/we/52/30.gif">15 Jun 2016: Partly Cloudy</div>
>   <div><img src="http://l.yimg.com/a/i/us/we/52/26.gif">16 Jun 2016: Cloudy</div>
>   <div><img src="http://l.yimg.com/a/i/us/we/52/39.gif">17 Jun 2016: Scattered Showers</div>
>   <div><img src="http://l.yimg.com/a/i/us/we/52/26.gif">18 Jun 2016: Cloudy</div>
>   <div><img src="http://l.yimg.com/a/i/us/we/52/28.gif">19 Jun 2016: Mostly Cloudy</div>

See it working in this JS Fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/igor_9000/u27br5Lg/2/

The weather API documentation here available here: https://developer.yahoo.com/weather/documentation.html

Hope that helps!

Comment: Awesome.  Glad you found it useful.  I forgot to mention the API documentation is here:  https://developer.yahoo.com/weather/documentation.html  It contains all the image codes and useful tidbits.