# Python: Get loaded resources from a web page (like chrome Dev tools)

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium-chromedriver

I'm trying to build a small python application which can detect downloaded resources (e.g. gifs, media files, etc) when a web page is loaded. Ideally this would be similar to the Chrome Dev-tools component in the Google Chrome Web Browser where one can click on the Network tab to fetch this data and resources that are downloaded dynamically.

I have tried to see if I can do this via Python Selenium, however I don't believe that this goes in too deep by seeing what resources are downloaded dynamically.

Is anyone able to confirm if this can be done in Python? Any help/ advice is appreciated.

thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Well, to do what you want, you basically need to write functions that extract what is supposed to be rendered (to be rendered, it needs to be fetched of course) from the server's response to you (in case of websites, the whole `html` content + response headers).

For example, you need to extract all the image links from the html using a regex like below:

```py
/(alt|title|src)=("[^"]*")/gi;
```

(Ref. [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37751281/using-regex-to-extract-an-image-url-from-string))

You also need to extract js files that are supposed to be loaded for the html file to be working properly.

You can use different tools to extract those kind of files.

> Is anyone able to confirm if this can be done in Python?

Yes

**Edit**

I think its best to mention that you should pay special attention to the Headers too. Cookies are the most important ones for sure.